# Remove c-programming, unix-programming, and windows-programming tags from Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, retag-request

I would suggest that [c-programming](/questions/tagged/c-programming) is completely unnecessary. As every question on the site should be programming related, [c](/questions/tagged/c) should suffice. For the nonce, I have retagged all three questions bearing [c-programming](/questions/tagged/c-programming).

I am less certain about [unix-programming](/questions/tagged/unix-programming). There are currently over 50 question tagged this way, and I can see an argument that it differentiates between questions about using Unix for programming and those about programming to the Unix API. None-the-less, I think that this argument is weak (we don't have [mac-programming](/questions/tagged/mac-programming), and [windows-programming](/questions/tagged/windows-programming) has only 7 questions).

I'm for getting rid of all three, and only using [unix](/questions/tagged/unix), [mac](/questions/tagged/mac), [windows](/questions/tagged/windows).

---

So far (September 25, 2009):

- 7 up votes
- 2 down vote
- 1 suggestion (4 net votes) to merge [c-programming](/questions/tagged/c-programming) with [c](/questions/tagged/c) and the various OS-programming tags with the plain OS tags.
- 1 suggestion (2 net votes) to kill [c-programming](/questions/tagged/c-programming), but keep the OS-programming tags
- 1 suggestion (0 net votes) to leave well enough alone.

A trend may be emerging, but still not much passion here, and I will take no further action unless and until a stronger consensus develops.

Comment: Nice edit, Chris. I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: Glad to be of service.

Comment: if you guys continue to abuse the `<kbd>` tag I'm going to pull the style.

Comment: Hadn't realized it was a problem, shall behave in the future. ::sticks out tongue and goes *wugga wugga wugga* behind Jeff's back::

Answer (score 7):

Couldn't these all just be merged with their non *programming counterparts?

If I have a C question that applies to windows-programming, it should be tagged "c", "windows".

I would say Unix programming should go the same way: e.g. a question could be tagged "bash", "unix" or perhaps just "shell-scripting".

Comment: This s what I was getting out. Will edit for clarity. Thanks.

Comment: 'Unix programming' is a pretty well known idea and can very easily be separate from bash, unix or shell-scripting.

Answer (score 2):

I would agree with c-programming but unix-programming or any os-programming should be left alone imo. Since you could be asking about specific elements of programming within that operating system.

But those tags could be combined with their os counterpart (unix-programming merged with unix or something)